# How do I get my small portable generator started?

Tags: generator, engine

My portable generator has been sitting for quite awhile.  I drained out the old gas and refilled.  Squirted carburetor cleaner.  Spray starting fluid it starts as long as starting fluid is squirted.  I am pretty sure the carburetor is gummed up.  How do I clear the line inside the carburetor.

Comment: This might be a good question for [mechanics](http://mechanics.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: To prevent, use gas stabilizer on stored equipment.

Answer (score 1):

Step one would be to drop float bowl and clean float pin and bowl.  The amount of gummy residue there will direct how much more disassembly/cleaning is needed.

The needle valves may also be gummed up.  If you remove them, count revolutions very carefully, for replacement.

Comment: Plus, most modern carburetors have a fixed main jet in the bolt that holds the bowl on. Give it a Blast with something like Berryman's Chemtool.

Answer (score 0):

I have had good luck with a product called "PB Blaster Lawn Mower Tune-Up in a Can". And yes that is really the name of the stuff. I remove the fuel line from the empty tank and spray it into the carb via the fuel line. Let it sit over night then add a small amount of fresh fuel the tank that has fuel stabilizer added to it. Try to start it. Spray a little of the PB Blaster into the carb if it starts. If it doesn't start them I would go ahead and start pulling apart the carb. To prevent this from happening in the first place I always use fuel stabilizer in all my small engines from the first use of the season to the last. Never leave fuel in the tank or carb for more than 30 days. Empty the tank and run the engine until it runs out of fuel.